# Уровни доступа

Tags: c#

Есть public, static, private, как их использовать? Для чего они нужны? И пример наиболее доступный, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну ёлки же палки... Задам-ка я глупый вопрос: а вы книгу по C# читали? Любую.

Comment: Кстати, у C# есть ещё `internal`.

Comment: ТС забанен в гугле, это распространенная проблема.

Comment: @Flammable: может, подскажете для ТС веб-адрес гугла и ключевые слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** Открываете вижуал студию или любой другой редактор

**1.2** Напротив классов, или свойств или методов или полей пишете как Вам душе угодно (или делаете копи паст, посмотрите в руководстве пользователя по выбранному Вами редактору текста) слова public, static, private, protected, internal

**2** Они нужны для ограничения области видимости классов и составляющих класса.

**3**

```
private internal class Example {

   private Example(){}

   public Example(int data){
      _data = data;
   }

   protected int _data;

   public int Data{ get{ return _data;} }

   public static void MyFunc(){
   }

}
```

:-D

А если серьёзно то почитайте [например это](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/23983/). Или погуглите.

Answer (score 6):

[Уровни доступности](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

> - **public** Неограниченный доступ.
> - **protected** Доступ ограничен содержащим классом или типами, которые являются производными от содержащего класса.
> - **internal** Доступ ограничен текущей сборкой.
> - **protected** internal Доступ ограничен текущей сборкой или типами, которые являются производными от содержащего класса.
> - **private** Доступ ограничен содержащим типом.

Дополнительные сведения смотрите в [спецификация языка C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228593.aspx).